# Installing KDE plugins

Tags: kde, plugins, effects

I want to compile and install KWin [Blur effect plugin](https://github.com/KDE/kwin/tree/ea05ac380b42a0009c7a69a84ea4a5b872c3db99/effects/blur)  to change the maximum possible blur.

[image: Blur adjustment window]

The maximum value of the slider is set [here](https://github.com/KDE/kwin/blob/ea05ac380b42a0009c7a69a84ea4a5b872c3db99/effects/blur/blur_config.ui#L115) and I want to change that.
But I don't know how to install that plugin?(with which tool and in which directory?)

Kubuntu 18.04
KWin & plasmashell : 5.12

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: *Always* include at least the output of `plasmashell --version` in your KDE questions. You can use the [edit] feature just below your question to do so.

Comment: A person deeply involved in the blur effect is quite [active on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/alex2580/). Perhaps, you'll get better guidance [at reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/). But keep in mind that although Plasma 5.12 is still supported, most developmental activity is now focused on the recently released Plasma 5.18.+ (and on developing Plasma 5.19).